# Get true or false for radio button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting data from my view, and using JavaScript to save.

HTML:

```
 <div>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => parts.ReturnRequired)
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => parts.ReturnRequired, true) Yes
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => parts.ReturnRequired, false) No
 </div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btPartHeaderSave').click(function () {
        var status = $('#parts_Status').val();
        var partsRequestOrderNum = $('#parts_PartsRequestOrderNum').val();
        var custShipping = $('#parts.CustShipping').val();
        var shipAddress1 = $('#parts_ShipAddress1').val();
        var shipAddress2 = $('#parts_ShipAddress2').val();
        var shipCounty = $('#parts_ShipCounty').val();
        var postCode = $('#parts_ShipPostCode').val();
        var deliveryType = $('#parts_DeliveryType').val();
        var notes = $('#parts_Notes').val();
        //var returnRequired = $('#ReturnRequired').val() == true;

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
            //url: "/Parts/PartHeaderSave",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                status: status, 
                partsRequestOrderNum: partsRequestOrderNum, 
                custShipping: custShipping, 
                shipAddress1: shipAddress1, 
                shipAddress2: shipAddress2, 
                shipCounty: shipCounty, 
                postCode: postCode, 
                deliveryType: deliveryType, 
                notes: notes, 
                returnRequired: returnRequired
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("You have sucessfully saved the header");
                alert(returnRequired);
                //   $('#alertSavePartOrderHeader1').addClass('in');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occured!!!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to get the value of `ReturnRequired`.

```
//var returnRequired = $('#ReturnRequired').val();
```

How do I set this up, to show in the database as `1` or `0`?
I am assuming using, `.val()` won't work.

For some reason, if I click yes it returns `0`, and if I click no, it still returns `0`, even though in my html I got my `true` / `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:checked` pseudo-class selector is applicable for checkboxes and radio buttons. This will convert the `boolean` value of the `checked` property to `0` or `1`:

```
var returnRequired = $('#ReturnRequired').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

You can also use the double tilde solution, but I do not think that the potential small performance gain is worth the lack of readability.

Another solution is using `Number` constructor, or using an implicite cast with the unary `+`. These are equivalent.

```
var returnRequired = new Number($('#ReturnRequired').is(':checked'));
var returnRequired = +$('#ReturnRequired').is(':checked');
```

You can depend on this solution, because the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) specifies, that `true` is converted to `1` and `false` to `0`.

Comment: Don't forget the unary `+` operator; [`+true` will give `1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787761/convert-true-1-and-false-0-in-javascript), and (at least in my opinion) it is a pretty obvious "cast to Number"

Comment: how come when i refresh the the screen it always shows False as default.... even though it is true?

Comment: Try putting `true` and `false` into quotation marks in the template. I am not familiar with ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1):

```
var getter = $('#ReturnRequired').prop('checked');
var setter = $('#ReturnRequired').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var returnRequired = $('#ReturnRequired').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the radio-button is checked or not. From there on, turning the boolean value into a number is very straight forward.

```
~~(true) //1
~~(false) //0
```